# Trying to verify fixed point having lower latency than float point

Tags: c++, runtime, fixed-point, approximate

I assumed that fixed point having lower latency and higher energy efficience than float point. So i try to verify that in my pc. I have Ubuntu 12.04,clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1,
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu. I compile following c++ code with command:
clang++ -O0 ShortVsInt.cpp -o ShortVsInt

But as result, i get:

```
used time for int 10613860 ns.
used time for short 10299391 ns.
used time for float 10453464 ns.
```

Here is my program

ShortVsInt.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

#define MatrixSize 10000000
#define loopSize 1

int main()
{
    int* i_a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*MatrixSize);
    int* i_b = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*MatrixSize);
    int* i_c = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*MatrixSize);
    // int i_a[MatrixSize];
    // int i_b[MatrixSize];
    // int i_c[MatrixSize];

    short* s_a=(short*) malloc(sizeof(short)*MatrixSize);
    short* s_b=(short*) malloc(sizeof(short)*MatrixSize);
    short* s_c=(short*) malloc(sizeof(short)*MatrixSize);

    float* f_a=(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*MatrixSize);
    float* f_b=(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*MatrixSize);
    float* f_c=(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*MatrixSize);

    std::mt19937 mt_random{static_cast<u_long>(time(0))};

    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_short(INT16_MIN, INT16_MAX);
    // std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_int(INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX);
    // std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_float(INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize; i++)
    {

        i_a[i]=static_cast<int>(dist_short(mt_random));
        i_b[i]=static_cast<int>(dist_short(mt_random));
        i_c[i]=static_cast<int>(0.0);

        s_a[i]=static_cast<short>(dist_short(mt_random));
        s_b[i]=static_cast<short>(dist_short(mt_random));
        s_c[i]=static_cast<short>(0.0);

        f_a[i]=static_cast<float>(dist_short(mt_random));
        f_b[i]=static_cast<float>(dist_short(mt_random));
        f_c[i]=static_cast<float>(0.0);

    }

    auto start_int = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int k=0; k<loopSize; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize; i++)
        {
            i_c[i]=i_a[i]*i_b[i]+i_a[i];
        }
    }
    auto end_int = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto time_int=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end_int - start_int);


    auto start_short = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int k=0; k<loopSize; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize; i++)
        {
            s_c[i]=s_a[i]*s_b[i]+s_a[i];
        }
    }
    auto end_short = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto time_short=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end_short - start_short);

    auto start_float = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(int k=0; k<loopSize; k++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MatrixSize; i++)
        {
            f_c[i]=f_a[i]*f_b[i]+f_a[i];
        }
    }
    auto end_float = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto time_float=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end_float - start_float);
    // printMatrix<float>(m_a, m_b,m_c);
    std::cout << "used time for int " << time_int.count()/loopSize << " ns."<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "used time for short " << time_short.count()/loopSize << " ns."<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "used time for float " << time_float.count()/loopSize << " ns."<< std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

i try to run the program more times and it shows me alway same resualt. Can someone give me any idea why the runtime of int and short operations ist not better than float. Does my compiler or chips do some optimization in background?

Comment: Why `-O0`?  It's not worth benchmarking unoptimised builds.  But, when you turn the optimiser on, you might get a surprise...

Comment: Measuring the performance of unoptimised code is fairly pointless, try again with optimisations enabled

Comment: "Its known that fixed point having lower latency and higher energy efficience than float point" - Says who?  Systems exist that have dedicated hardware for fixed point arithmetic and some have the same for floating point, so I'm not convinced that that statement is generally true.

Comment: With -O2 on my decade-old laptop: `used time for int 111 ns. used time for short 59 ns. used time for float 64 ns.` (It is a curious fact that so many statements that begin with "it is known that..." are untrue.)

Comment: I tried to fix the wording to prevent discussion about the "it is known.." anti-phrase. If you can provide any reference for that claim you should add it.

Comment: `clang++ -O0` -- As mentioned, this is worthless if you are actually testing the speed of a C++ program.

Comment: interesting quickbench results: https://quick-bench.com/q/cB8oMoNWbbgsnxgWWBlnxI8AazQ

Comment: @AlanBirtles maybe it is somehow related to CPU cache and pipelining. I.e. float is faster than int because CPU can do float math and int math (increment counter) simultanously. short is faster than float because three arrays[10000] of the short consume two times less memory than three arrays of float. Maybe vectorization also comes into the game. CPU can process two times more shorts at one shot than int/floats.